# Canvas' fps unintentionally speeding up?

Tags: javascript, canvas, frame-rate

I am messing around with the canvas element based off of tutorials online and have constructed the following page, [here](http://www.tiletabs.com/game/).

Here is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Canvas Game</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <h1>Cool Canvas Bouncing Effect!</h1>
        <p>Which would you like to see bounce around?</p>
        <input id="beachBallButton" type="button" value="Beach Ball" />
        <input id="avatarButton" type="button" value="Avatar" />
    </header>
    <br />
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="400">
        Your browser does not support canvas!
    </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

const FPS;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var xDirection = 1;
var yDirection = 1;
var image = new Image();
image.src = null;
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

$('#avatarButton').click(function() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    FPS = 30;
    image.src = 'avatar.png';

    setInterval(draw, 1000 / FPS);

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);

        x += 1 * xDirection;
        y += 1 * yDirection;

        if (x >= 500)
        {
            x = 500;
            xDirection = -1;
        }
        else if (x <= 0)
        {
            x = 0;
            xDirection = 1;
        }

        if (y >= 300)
        {
            y = 300;
            yDirection = -1;
        }
        else if (y <= 0)
        {
            y = 0;
            yDirection = 1;
        }
    }
});

$('#beachBallButton').click(function() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    FPS = 60;
    image.src = 'beachball.png';

    setInterval(draw, 1000 / FPS);

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(image, x, y);

        x += 5 * xDirection;
        y += 5 * yDirection;

        if (x >= 450)
        {
            x = 450;
            xDirection = -1;
        }
        else if (x <= 0)
        {
            x = 0;
            xDirection = 1;
        }

        if (y >= 250)
        {
            y = 250;
            yDirection = -1;
        }
        else if (y <= 0)
        {
            y = 0;
            yDirection = 1;
        }
    }
});

});
```

Now, say you click on the `Avatar` button, and then click on the `Beach Ball` afterwards, the FPS is sped up.  However, I reset the FPS variable within the `click` functions of both functions.  I also reset the `x` and `y` variables.

Additionally, I could just keep clicking the *same* button and the speed will increase dramatically as well.

Could someone help explain why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MMM..... const FPS; <--- What is this?

As far as I remember, there is no constants in javascript. Anyway, if it is a constant, why you try to set it's value later several times? I think that this statement fails and the first time you set the FPS, you create a global var, and later this global var is shared by all the functions.

Also, you don't use clearInterval, and you are invoking a new setInterval every time you make a click, so if you click 3 times in "beachBallButton", you will have 3 setIntervals functions running, each of them executing the code. This is likely to cause the "speed up".

Comment: Wow, how could I have missed myself trying to assign a constant a variable.  I adapted this from a tutorial online so it wasn't a problem before.. xD  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this a working example => http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/sLpCA/

Just some 'additions' to what Alejandro said (that is correct), no constants in JS. So you need to 'declare' `var FPS` at the beginning.

Moreover, you have to set an 'intervalID' variable, that is what the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) returns when you call it. BUT, before each setInterval call, you need to [remove the 'active' interval actions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval) you called (note that the first time there's nothing to clear)

```
var myInterval;
/* ... */
clearInterval(myInterval)
myInterval = setInterval(draw,1000/FPS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of `setInterval`, that really helped!

Comment: Np pal, happy to hear that it helped :)